# How can I modify a screensaver (.saver)?

Tags: xcode, opengl, nib, screensaver

My goal is to be able to modify a Matrix screensaver that is no longer being supported by the developers. I simply want to be able to change the color of the glyphs from *green* to *red*. From what I've read, I might need to edit the compiled `.nib` file. And supposedly, there are tricks to do this.

The only files I see within the `.saver` file are:

- Unix Executable File
- InfoPlist.strings
- Matrix.nib
- a Glyphs.png (its in grayscale, so the color affect must come from programming)
- A *Matrix.nib* file in a folder entitled *Japanese.lproj*

I don't see any other files that I could edit that would let me achieve this, so I am looking for some guidance.

EDIT:  The author posted the source code for his screensaver on his [github](https://github.com/lpar/RedPill). Now i'm just trying to figure out exactly what needs to be changed.

Comment: What's the github link?

Comment: https://github.com/lpar/RedPill   sorry, thought I put that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modification of the source code isn't very hard. The colors are computed on the fly, so an asset can't be modified to change the color.

In line 226 of MatrixStrip.m change the 1 before the left bracket to a 0. In Line 228 Change the 0 to a 1. The column below the V in the code.

```
....                            V
226:    colorArray[16*i + 4*c + 0] = (cellState[i] == 0) ? 0.0 : g;
227:    // Cells which are very bright are slightly whitened
228:    colorArray[16*i + 4*c + 1] = ((g > 0.7) && (cellState[i] != 0)) ? (g - 0.6) : 0.0;
```

Make the same change to lines 253 and 255. You are putting the numbers in column column 34 in the inner loops in order. In the original code, reading down column 34 the numbers a 1, 0, 2, 3. This has to be done in both of the inner loops on the 4 lines I indicated. These numbers are the indices to the RGBA color.

I'm not sure if my explanation is adequate, so instead of expanding this to 1000 words, I'll include a screen shot of the diff with the relevant parts highlighted by Kaleidoscope. The original code is on the left.

[image]

I had to download the image to see the relevant details.

Comment: thanks, I actually figured that out immediately posted that. But now, the problems is that when I build it and test it out, I get red Blocks now instead of Glyphs like its supposed to be. And I don't know what's causing it. My only guess is that it's the way I build the project in xCode.

Comment: Is that the only change you made? When I tested what I posted, it ran fine. In fact, I've got purple glyphs now. Is anything coming up in console.app? There are some good logging functions that are called a lot. You can use Xcode to verify that only those four changes were made and revert anything else. I am running with the project & nib files unmodified.

Comment: I'm sure I screwed something up (typical me). Probably didn't export the saver file in the correct manner. I had to go into the debug folder to find the .saver file. Not sure if that's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: All you need to do is copy the saver file to "~/Library/Screen Savers" and restart System Preferences. It may not be your fault. It may be the video card. I'm running on a 15" MacBook Pro Retina with a 27" Thunderbolt display. Also, did you run it before making any modifications to verify it actually runs correctly?

Comment: crap! all I had to do was restart system preferences. Wow, that was about of hour wasted. lol.  Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: How were you able to determine how to determine which color will be produced? I've been searching around for color code charts and such in RGBA and haven't been able to find anything that will help me.

Comment: You can check out Wikipedia for info on the RGB color space. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model The "A" stands for the Alpha channel, which is the amount of transparency for the color. Wiht the way the code is written, it is pretty easy to get the text to be any of the primary (Red, Green, Blue) or secondary (Purple, Yellow, Cyan) colors, and probably white and black, although I haven't tried these two. To get other colors the way the colors are calculated needs to be changed, not just the ordering of the color components (R, G, B).